# Aurelia KendoUI Bridge not doing anything

Tags: kendo-ui, aurelia

I am trying to get the Aurelia KendoUI Bridge to work, but it appears to be doing nothing at all: Any element created by the KendoUI Bridge only appears as the basic HTML but does not have the kendo parts (for example a date picker appears just as an input box, without the date selector).

- I have installed both the KendoUI and the Kendou UI Bridge as per the
  instructions (via jspm).
- I can show Kendo elements ok "old style", i.e. with $(myElement).kendoDatePicker({...}). I am therefore assuming the issue is with the configuration of the bridge, not with kendo.
- The bridge has what I believe to be the correct entries in config.js
- The console confirms that the bridge itself has loaded ok, has loaded a total of 67 wrappers and shows **no errors**.

I don't know what else to look for - any pointers most welcome. Thanks!

**index.html:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="js/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo/kendo.datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div aurelia-app="main" style="height: 100%">
    <div class="splash">
        <div class="message">Starting engine ...</div>
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
</div>
```

**main.js:**

```js
import 'bootstrap';
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';

    
export function configure(aurelia) {

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .feature('./components')
        .feature('./views')
        .plugin('aurelia-computed')
        .plugin('aurelia-kendoui-bridge', kendo => kendo.pro());

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

**customElement.js**

```js
import 'js/kendo/kendo.datepicker.min';

export class Countries {

    bind() {
      $('#datepicker').kendoDatePicker();  // this works as expected and shows a full kendo date picker
    }
}
```

**customElement.html**

```html
<template>
    
    <require from="aurelia-kendoui-bridge/datepicker/datepicker"></require>

    <div id="example">
        <div class="k-content">
            <h4>Show e-mails from:</h4>
            <input id="datepicker" style="width: 200px" /> <!-- works ok when setting the kendo widget in viewmodel -->
           
            <input ak-datepicker="k-value.bind: '1/11/2016'" /> <!-- doesn't work, shows just the input box-->
            <input ak-datepicker ak-datepicker.ref="datepicker" style="width: 100%" /> <!-- neither does this (also just the input box) -->
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

With your sample above, I've reproduced a [gistrun example](https://gist.run?id=1ce2ea86461456aac47c2064663fa52b) which works.

The only difference with your code is basically that I've removed the import:

```
import 'js/kendo/kendo.datepicker.min';
```

If you are **not planning** on using it in your .js models, please don't add it.

'Importing' it as you mentioned is [documented in the TypeScript section](https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.gitbooks.io/kendoui-bridge-docs/content/developers-tutorials/44_typescript.html). So you've done well there. But in practice though, I believe it needs to be like this:

```
import 'kendo/js/kendo.datepicker';
```

At least, that is my experience when using an Aurelia CLI app with TypeScript and the Kendo UI bridge. Having a wrong import in my .ts files will reproduce the behaviour you mention.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your thoughts. However, in my case the path to the kendo file was actually correct. The real solution comprised two elements: 1. "Enhance" the inserted Aurelia template and 2. attach the resulting view. I have prepared a gist run that shows how it works: https://gist.run/?id=5d2ee91f2ce44aa42ef8de084771b4ba